# how to write data to an Excel file in iOS App?

Tags: ios, excel

I found a sample project named [DHlibxls](https://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls) could read file from Excel.

But... the problem is, I wanna write data to Excel file.

My idea is store an excel file template in the app, and write data to the excel file by actions user did in the app and thus create a new excel file for emailing..

PS: Don't urge me to convert to CSV or other format, the client's tough and he insists on the excel format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i create excel sheet and file in iPhone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775661/how-can-i-create-excel-sheet-and-file-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: I had viewed that answer as well. now I am studying it.   There are some compile errors with that sample project... anyway, let me try to figure it out... and paste the errors if I it's too hard for me.

Comment: Have you got the solution then please post the answer?

Comment: @user2243758 you can use pods.. but it only support xls. not xlsx https://cocoapods.org/pods/JXLS