# iPad app as wrapper for Excel Model

Tags: ios, ipad, excel

I've got an Excel file that takes ~10 inputs and outputs ~5 numbers. The problem is, the calculations run involve lots of assumptions, are rather complex, and laid out over 5 excel sheets with lots of lookup tables, etc.

I'd like to wrap the Excel model in an iPad app -- so that it's easy to solicit user input and show the easy outputs without having them to see the dirty work beneath.

It's important for me to encapsulate the Excel model since that's still getting tweaked and adjusted... so to have a wrapper set up as opposed to reproduce the logic in the Excel file would save me probably 2 orders of magnitude of time.

Have looked around and not found a way to do this yet... any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: If you think about how complex Excel must be to handle all those dependencies, then its just not realistic to think you can find an processing engine to replace Excel itself. I maintain the open source Excel read and write projects on SourceForge, and just doing that is a massive amount of work. The only possible solution would be to port all the OpenOffice code but that would be a gigantic amount of work. I suspect using the web to interface to a server engine is going to be your best option.

Answer (score 2):

Two options come to mind.

One is that you can use an excel wrapper on iOS. Details can be found here: [How can i create excel sheet and file in iPhone sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775661/how-can-i-create-excel-sheet-and-file-in-iphone-sdk)

The second option is to setup a server and pass the task onto the server. I'm familiar with Ruby, and creating/modifying excel files in Ruby is a breeze. I'd expect PHP, python, etc. to have similar faculties.

Either option is going to depend on your use case, whether you're charging for the app or not, and your familiarity with server side programming.

Comment: Can you point me to how to handle CRUD ops using server side languages (Ruby/Python/PHP)? The amount of scripting on top should literally be setting the contents of ~10 cells and reading out the contents of ~5 cells, so hopefully simple read/write access is enough to then set up a web service that the iPad app can send requests to.

Comment: @R.K. have a gander at Roo: http://roo.rubyforge.org/. The page is ugly as hell, but the gem works great. You can pair that with a `Sinatra` web front end to handle `POST`ing to the server. Does that help answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Roo only has read-access to Excel files... it supports write access to Google Spreadsheets but not Excel. I'm scripting language-agnostic so I wonder if you know of any libraries in other Python/PHP/other that enable write access to Excel files?

Comment: @R.K. my bad. Have a look then at https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet I've never used it, but it  claims it can write to excel.