# Core Data SQLite File

Tags: sqlite, core-data, swift

I have an app that saves your data and retrieves your data under a ID number of your choice! The only thing is I have people asking for an excel document of all there saved data! Does anyone know how I would go ahead with this! I am using Swift and Xcode 6.1! I am also using a SQLite file that core data has made for me.

Thanks,
AppSwiftGB

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i create excel sheet and file in iPhone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775661/how-can-i-create-excel-sheet-and-file-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: @Wain This was 3 years out of date and in objective-c!! And this is in swift! And Xcode 6!

Comment: Did you search github for alternatives?

Comment: @Wain Not really, Why?

Comment: Because you should always Google search for duplicate questions and 3rd party code solutions before posting questions.

Comment: I searched Google and only found projects on ios 5 and earlier versions of what I needed. But anyway do you know how to do this, seen as that was my question. @Wain

Comment: Xcode version and swift make little difference, use one of the solutions from github (converting to swift if you need to).

Comment: But does anyone know how I could do this without going on github e.g. The code that will make csv file!

Comment: https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Answer (score 0):

Creating native Excel is likely a PITA. You should export to CSV, though the format seems to be another PITA for one is liking comma, the other semicolon and the third tabs :-(